# YAML Form Conditional Page

Tags: forms, 8

Is there any option in YAML Form to create conditional page? There is already conditional fields option. But I can not find conditional page option.

What actually I want to do is to take some additional information on another page of the form if there some specific value is selected.

Answer (score 1):

I was recently at the NYC Drupal meetup where the maintainer mentioned this exact feature. He said that it is on the road map, but it does not exist yet. That said, he is *very* open to patches :)

Incidentally, please note that the YAML form module was renamed to Webform.

Comment: Thanks for the update. Yes I recently noticed that name change.